# How to handle optional named parameters chaining

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure how to explain it properly, so let's look at an example:

```
class Shape {
  Colors color;
  Shape({
  this.color = Colors.black
  });
  
  factory Shape.Circle({
   Colors? color
}) {
    return Shape(color: color ?? Colors.black);
  }
  
}
```

Now ideally, I just want to give value to optional `color` field in the class, and not repeat it on every factory, or constructor. But I am not sure how to achieve that concisely.
I understand that I can have a `if` statement and create `Shape`  according to the fact that `color` is null or not, but that seems very ugly.

Comment: There is no way to duplicate default values.  I would just make the main `Shape` constructor be `Shape({Colors? color}) : color = color ?? Colors.black;`, and then let all other constructors use `null` as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Shape {
  Colors? color;
  Shape({
  this.color = Colors.black
  }); 
  
}
```

Comment: I don't want to sacrifice my type though